# how is content_for being used here

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an old Rails app that has the following:

```
= content_for :js
```

I've seen the block format before but never without a block and am a bit confused as to what it's telling me here. The docs seem to imply that it is similar to yield'ing in like a layout. Does that mean there's some string called `js` that it's outputting?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method defnition of [content_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for), this means that there should be a block defined for this.

```
<% content_for :js do %>
  # Do Something 
<% end %>
```

By this way, you can call `= content_for :js` from other parts of the code.

Hope this helps!